# Looping to check for number of repeats of each element in array - stuck during while

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique

Say I have the following array,

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 1, 1];
```

I'm trying to write a function that loops through each element and checks if there is a repeat. For example, "does `x(1) == x(2)` OR does `x(1) == x(3)` OR ... does `x(1) == x(9)`". I have the following code so far:

```
N = length(x);    
sharedPosition = zeros(1, N);

for i = 1:N    
    for j = 1:N
        indexSum = i + j;    
        while indexSum <= N    
            isShared = x(1, i) == x(1, i+j);    
            sharedPosition(1, i) = sum(isShared);    
        end    
    end    
end
```

However, the code never seems to make it past even the first iteration and idles with "Busy". How can better implement this code?

Comment: If you are not specifically required to do this manually, here's a more Matlab-like way to do it: `sum(bsxfun(@eq, x, x.'))`. Or, in recent versions, `sum(x==x.')`

Comment: @LuisMendo  I did not know about the change to implicit expansion in recent versions.   At my company we are just now implementing 2016b and testing legacy code.  That is certain something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you never change `indexSum` or `N` inside the `while`, so the loop condition is always true!

---

You could do this without a `while` and just one `for`

```
% size and numel are usually preferred over length, as it's ambiguous which dimension
% you are getting the "length" of.
N = numel(x); 
sharedPosition = zeros(1, N);

% Loop over values
for ii = 1:N
    % Store the number of times the given value occurs
    % MATLAB can compare a scalar to an entire array, no need to loop again.
    sharedPosition(ii) = sum(x(ii) == x);
end
```